# What is the correct file path for a UNIX TCP Socket running on a virtualized IP?

Tags: sockets, unix, tcp, telnet

I'm trying to virtualize a telnet server for multiple ip address's. While still being able to talk to the same remote servers.

What is the correct file path for a UNIX TCP Socket running on a virtualized IP? Or is there a way of connecting locally and ignoring the routing tables?

I have virtualized the IP's on loopback as follows:

```
 lo0: flags=8049<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 16384
    options=3<RXCSUM,TXCSUM>
    inet6 ::1 prefixlen 128 
    inet 127.0.0.1 netmask 0xff000000 
    inet6 fe80::1%lo0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x1 
    inet 10.10.0.24 netmask 0xff000000  
    inet 192.168.10.2 netmask 0xffffff00 
    inet 192.168.10.3 netmask 0xffffff00 
    inet 192.168.10.4 netmask 0xffffff00  
    nd6 options=1<PERFORMNUD>
```

The Routing table is configured with static routes so that the outbound connection can still reach the intended destination. (I have tried turning this off and it still didn't help)

```
Routing tables
Internet:
Destination        Gateway            Flags        Refs      Use   Netif Expire

192.168.10.2       192.168.10.2       UH              0       75     en1
192.168.10.3       192.168.10.3       UH              0       75     en1
192.168.10.4       192.168.10.4       UH              0       75     en1
```

I can confirm that the servers are listening and bound to the correct socket.

```
sudo lsof -i -n | \grep 'telnet'
Python    69212           root    6u  IPv4 0x7002eb6c7a9b50e1      0t0    TCP 192.168.10.4:telnet (LISTEN)
Python    69212           root    7u  IPv4 0x7002eb6c7db219b1      0t0    TCP 192.168.10.3:telnet (LISTEN)
Python    69212           root    8u  IPv4 0x7002eb6c4f254b51      0t0    TCP 192.168.10.2:telnet (LISTEN)
```

I have tried a few different ways of connecting to the local server. And have removed the local servers so I can prove that I am connecting locally.

```
telnet -u /dev/tcp/192.168.10.5/23
    Trying /dev/tcp/192.168.10.5/23...
    /dev/tcp/192.168.10.5/23: No such file or directory

socat -v READLINE UNIX-CONNECT:/dev/tcp/192.168.10.5/23
    2015/01/27 11:32:39 socat[92588] E connect(6, LEN=26 AF=1 "/dev/tcp/192.168.10.5/23", 26): No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing things up.

UNIX sockets are one thing: they use objects in the file system which have paths and can be addressed with them.

TCP/IP sockets are another thing. You can do the same over them, but you address them differently.

With telnet, you would do

```
telnet -u 192.168.10.5
```

and with socat it is like

```
socat -v READLINE TCP:192.168.10.5:23
```

The `/dev/tcp` stuff is just a thing made up by the shell; it does not really exist.

Comment: The socat version works a charm. When I run `telnet -u 192.168.10.5` I get back `192.168.10.5: ai_family not supported`. In looking at the documentation in a bit more detail, I need the AF_UNIX address. I'm curious now, is there a way of getting an AF_UNIX address from the ip and the port? I guess I hoped that was what was happening under the covers of /dev/tcp/hostname/port

Comment: @Luke Again, there is no `AF_UNIX` address for a TCP/IP connection. These are completely distinct namespaces. I don't know why it doesn't work with `telnet`...

Comment: BTW, what does `-u` do on your version of `telnet`?

Comment: The BSD flavour `Forces telnet to use AF_UNIX addresses only`. I worked out the issue though, I was using a relative path(./path-to-socket) rather than fully qualified path to the socket $(pwd)/path_to_socket. Not 100% sure why that matters, but its working now with telnet -u